# sinon spy doesn't register call in a generator loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, generator, sinon

I want to check that a piece of code is being called, so I'm using a sinon spy to assert this.  However, the spy seems to be failing, despite console.logs showing that the code has been called correctly.

I'm wondering if my function being a generator is causing my spy to misreport what it's doing.

my code (i've taken out some chunks for brevity):

```
  isBlacklisted(release, jobUUID) {

    names.forEach((name) => {
      this._spawnPythonProcessGenerator(
        this.IS_BLACKLISTED_SCRIPT,
        name
      ).next().value
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this._errorEvent(release, name, err, jobUUID);
        });
    }, this);
  }

  _errorEvent(release, name, err, jobUUID) {
    console.log('got here');
  }

  *_spawnPythonProcessGenerator(scriptSrc, name) {
    const pythonProcess = this._childProcess.spawn(
      'python3',
      [...arguments]
    );
    yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
        reject(err.toString());
      });

      pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        resolve(data.toString());
      });
    });
  }
```

and my tests:

```
const Blacklist = require('../../src/Blacklist2');
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

describe('Blacklist', () => {
  let blacklist;
  beforeEach(() => {
    blacklist = new Blacklist(childProcess);
    blacklist.IS_BLACKLISTED_SCRIPT = './test/helpers/good.py';
  });
  describe('isBlacklisted', () => {
    it('should call the _errorEvent for every name in a release when the blacklist application is not available', async () => {
      let release = {
        id: 1001,
        asset_controller: {
          id: 54321,
        },
        display_name: 'Blah',
        names: [
          {
            id: 2001,
            name: 'Blah',
          },
        ],
      };

      blacklist.IS_BLACKLISTED_SCRIPT = './test/helpers/'+ uuid() +'.py';


      const spy = sinon.spy(blacklist, '_errorEvent');
      blacklist.isBlacklisted(release, uuid());

      console.log(spy);
      sinon.assert.calledTwice(spy);
      spy.restore();
    });
  });
});
```

my spy reports:

> notCalled: true

Comment: Hmm the test suggests it should call `_errorEvent` for the number of names - the test is checking for 2 but the test data only has one name?

Comment: Ahh sorry @James, I took some code out, but basically names is an array of `display_name` and `name` from the names array.  if the names array had 11 entries, then theoretically `_errorEvent` might be called 12 times.  Even so, if you were correct my spy should report `calledOnce`, not `notCalled`.

Comment: Your problem lies with asynchrony, not with the generator. You need `isBlacklisted` to return a promise you can wait on. Otherwise  your assertion happens before the spy is called.

Comment: @sripberger is right, doesn't look like `isBlackisted` is propagating the Promises from `_spawnPythonProcessGenerator` therefore your test has no means of waiting on the Promise to resolve. You can verify this by moving your assertion into a `setTimeout` (this would involve calling `done` for the test manually in the callback). The test should pass, you will need to update `isBlacklisted` to return a `Promise` you can handle in your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll expand my comment into an actual answer, hopefully that helps.

Your problem lies with asynchrony, not with the generator. You need isBlacklisted to return a promise you can wait on. Otherwise your assertion happens before the spy is called.

Something like this:

```
isBlacklisted(release, jobUUID) {
    let promises = names.map((name) => {
      return this._spawnPythonProcessGenerator(
        this.IS_BLACKLISTED_SCRIPT,
        name
      ).next().value
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this._errorEvent(release, name, err, jobUUID);
        });
    }, this);

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Then, in your test:

```
return blacklist.isBlacklisted(release, uuid())
    .then(() => {
        sinon.assert.calledTwice(spy);
    });
```

Also... This isn't related to your problem, but your `_spawnPythonProcessGenerator` method doesn't need to be a generator. You're only using the first value of it by calling `next` like that and calling the whole thing over again for each array item.

It will work the same if you take out the `*`, change `yield` to `return`, and  skip the `.next().value` when you call it. You also probably want to rename it because it's not a generator.

```
_spawnPythonProcess(scriptSrc, name) {
    const pythonProcess = this._childProcess.spawn(
      'python3',
      [...arguments]
    );
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
        reject(err.toString());
      });

      pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        resolve(data.toString());
      });
    });
}
```

When you call it:

```
let promises = names.map((name) => {
  return this._spawnPythonProcess(
    this.IS_BLACKLISTED_SCRIPT,
    name
  )
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this._errorEvent(release, name, err, jobUUID);
    });
}, this);

return Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer... I must admit I don't recall why I made it a generator

Comment: @sripberger expanding your comment in an answer helped me, your hope is now fulfilled, thanx